# Dynamically add link to current item edit form

Tags: 2013, list, column, calculated-column, edit-form

I want to show list in Standard list view, with couple of columns, one of those columns would be link to custom edit form of that item.

I know this can be done pretty easily in SP designer, but I need to do it in SharePoint itself. Is this possible and if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have `ID` field in you view, and you want to have a hyperlink on it which will redirect to`CustomEditForm.aspx`.
Earlier we used to do it with SharePoint Designer, but in SharePoint 2013 they have introduced CSR to do such customization in list Views/Forms.

Please refer below steps.

1. Create a JS file and paste below mentioned code.
2. Edit List View page with browser.
3. Edit web part properties of List View and add JS Link reference of this js file (e.g. ~sitecollection/SiteAssets/CustomCSR.js)
4. Save web part properties and page.

   ```
   (function () {
     function registerRenderer() {
       var ctxForm = {};
       ctxForm.Templates = {}; 
       ctxForm.Templates = {
           Fields : {
               'ID': {
                   View : function (ctx) {
                       var url = String.format('{0}?ID={1}', "/Lists/ListA/CustomEditForm.aspx", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                       return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                   }
               },
           }
       };
       SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
   }
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
   })();
   ```

Answer (score 3):

On *List Tools* menu, select *Modify View*. In columns section on page, you can select *Edit (link to edit item)* as column. This will add a button to list which is directly opens edit item form on list item.

Comment: you didn't read my question entirely :) edit form I need is not default edit form.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. This works for me both InfoPath forms and default forms :) How did you create your edit form?

Comment: Thank you on help anyway. For effort I clicked useful answer :) I created it in SP Designer.

Answer (score 2):

Beside great response by Yayati, found out **No coding** solution today.

1) Create a **Calculated column**
2) Set the formula to

```
="<a href='http://...../sites/mySiteName/Lists/myListName/CustomEditForm.aspx?ID="&ID&"&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read'>View Details</a>"
```

3) make sure to set your Calculated Output type to **NUMBER** and **not text**.

Voila, it works.
Some of help found [here](https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/).